# xpath get element by index

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the below xpath expression

```
//div[@class="post-content"]//img
```

which runs on a html page, scanning for images.
The above query returns a lot of images but I only want the second in the list.

I have tried these with no luck:

```
//div[@class="post-content"]//img[1] and
//div[@class="post-content"]//img[position()=1]
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In XPath index starts from 1 position, therefore

```
//div[@class="post-content"]//img[2]
```

should work correctly if you have to select each 2nd `img` in `div[@class="post-content"]`.
If you want to select only 2nd `img` from all images that are in `div[@class="post-content"]`, use:

```
(//div[@class="post-content"]//img)[2]
```

Comment: Excellent. Though I was not clear, you hit it. The second one is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 14):

indexes in XPath are 1-based, not 0-based.  Try

```
(//div[@class="post-content"]//img)[position()=2]
```

Comment: Of course XPath indexes are 1-based... what the hell XPath?