# Protractor element by Xpath Index

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-node, jasmine2.0

I am trying to get xpath by index and i am not making an progress. protractor says "that the element has more than one element is found for locator choosing the 1st one". however I want to make sure that the 1st one is selected intentionally screen shot below:

[image]
My code: that is not working:
[image]
I tried the following site nothing works:
https://devhints.io/xpath
[xpath get element by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025221/xpath-get-element-by-index)
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `var paylroll = element(by.xpath('(//*[text()="Payroll"])[1]'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var payroll = element.all(by.xpath('//*[text()="Payroll"]')).first();
```

Comment: Wow I i almost had it thanks for your help it worked