# Unable to select date from datepicker calendar in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

I'd like to use python selenium to search at https://book.spicejet.com/Search.aspx

I reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039454/unable-to-select-depart-date-in-https-spicejet-com-through-selenium-and-java) question but it is not the right answer what I am looking for.

I searched for a flight from Kolkata to Goa with 2 adults and 2 Infants. When I am giving passenger details I couldn't able to select infants Date of birth.

```
import time
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

booking_url = "https://book.spicejet.com/Search.aspx"
browser.get(booking_url)

departureButton = browser.find_element_by_id("ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchVieworiginStation1_CTXT").click()

browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Kolkata").click()

arivalButton = browser.find_element_by_id("ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchViewdestinationStation1_CTXT")
arivalButton.click()
time.sleep(.3)
arivalButton.send_keys("Goa")
time.sleep(1)
search_date = "20-September 2019"
dep_date = search_date.split("-")

dep_month = dep_date[1]
dep_day = dep_date[0]

while browser.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-title").text != dep_month:
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title='Next']").click()

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//table//a[text()='"+dep_day+"']").click()
time.sleep(1)

try:
    return_date_close = browser.find_element_by_class_name("date-close").click
except:
    pass


pax_selct = browser.find_element_by_id("divpaxinfo").click()
time.sleep(.2)

# __________Adult number_____________

for i in range(0, 2 - 1):
    adults = browser.find_element_by_id("hrefIncAdt")
    adults.click()
# ____________Set Num of Children___________________
for i in range(0, 0):
    childrens = browser.find_element_by_id("hrefIncChd")
    childrens.click()
# ____________Set Num of Infant(s)___________________
for i in range(0, 2):
    infants = browser.find_element_by_id("hrefIncInf")
    infants.click()

donebttn = browser.find_element_by_id("btnclosepaxoption").click()
searchBtn = browser.find_element_by_class_name("bookbtn").click()

browser.switch_to.default_content()
flightarr = []
tbl_row = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("fare-row")
time_select=3
price_select=1
new_time_serial = 0
tr_cont = 4
for item in tbl_row:
      if item.is_displayed():
            if new_time_serial == time_select:
                  col = item
                  cont = str(tr_cont)
                  if price_select == 0:
                        price1 = col.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="availabilityTable0"]/tbody/tr['+cont+']/td[3]/p').click()
                  elif price_select == 1:
                        price2 = col.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="availabilityTable0"]/tbody/tr['+cont+']/td[4]/p').click()

            new_time_serial = new_time_serial + 1
      tr_cont = tr_cont + 1

time.sleep(1)
cntn_btn = browser.find_element_by_class_name("button-continue").click()
passen_serial = 0
passen_serial_inf = 0
#inf = 1

birth_year = "2017"
birth_month = "Nov"
birth_day = "30"

all_pass_frm = browser.find_element_by_class_name("multicontent")
all_pass_entry = all_pass_frm.find_elements_by_class_name("sectionContent")

for passen in all_pass_entry:
    pass_type = passen.find_element_by_class_name("guest-heading").text.split(' ',1)[0]
    pass_type2 = passen.find_element_by_class_name("guest-heading").text.split(' ',1)[1]

    if pass_type == "Adult":
        deg_sel_name = Select(passen.find_element_by_id("CONTROLGROUPPASSENGER_PassengerInputViewPassengerView_DropDownListTitle_" + str(passen_serial) + ""))
        deg_sel_name.select_by_index(1)

        first_name_in = passen.find_element_by_id("CONTROLGROUPPASSENGER_PassengerInputViewPassengerView_TextBoxFirstName_" + str(passen_serial) + "")
        first_name_in.send_keys("imam")

        last_name_in = passen.find_element_by_id("CONTROLGROUPPASSENGER_PassengerInputViewPassengerView_TextBoxLastName_" + str(passen_serial) + "")
        last_name_in.send_keys("Hossain")

    elif pass_type == "Child":

        deg_sel_name = Select(passen.find_element_by_id("CONTROLGROUPPASSENGER_PassengerInputViewPassengerView_DropDownListGender_" + str(passen_serial) + ""))
        deg_sel_name.select_by_index(2)

        first_name_in = passen.find_element_by_id("CONTROLGROUPPASSENGER_PassengerInputViewPassengerView_TextBoxFirstName_" + str(passen_serial) + "")
        first_name_in.send_keys("Korim")

        last_name_in = passen.find_element_by_id("CONTROLGROUPPASSENGER_PassengerInputViewPassengerView_TextBoxLastName_" + str(passen_serial) + "")
        last_name_in.send_keys("Hossain")

    elif pass_type == "Infant":
        deg_sel_name = Select(passen.find_element_by_id("CONTROLGROUPPASSENGER_PassengerInputViewPassengerView_DropDownListGender_"+ str(passen_serial_inf) + "_" + str(passen_serial_inf) + ""))
        deg_sel_name.select_by_index(2)

        first_name_in = passen.find_element_by_id("CONTROLGROUPPASSENGER_PassengerInputViewPassengerView_TextBoxFirstName_"+ str(passen_serial_inf) + "_" + str(passen_serial_inf) + "")
        first_name_in.send_keys("Aqiba")

        last_name_in = passen.find_element_by_id("CONTROLGROUPPASSENGER_PassengerInputViewPassengerView_TextBoxLastName_"+ str(passen_serial_inf) + "_" + str(passen_serial_inf) + "")
        last_name_in.send_keys("Hassan")

        dob = passen.find_element_by_id("inputDateContactInfant" +str(pass_type2)+ "").click()
        dob_cal = browser.find_element_by_class_name("datepickerViewYears")
        dob_cal_year = dob_cal.find_element_by_class_name("datepickerYears")
        inf_birth_year = dob_cal.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class="datepickerYears"]/tr/td/a/span[text()="'+birth_year+'"]').click()
        inf_birth_mon = dob_cal.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class="datepickerMonths"]/tr/td/a/span[text()="'+birth_month+'"]').click()
        inf_birth_day = dob_cal.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class="datepickerDays"]/tr/td/a/span[text()="'+birth_day+'"]').click()


    #   inf = inf +1 
        passen_serial_inf = passen_serial_inf + 1
    passen_serial = passen_serial + 1


print("Done")
```

I tried with xPath it works for 1st infant but it is not working for 2nd infant. What should i need to do now? is there any way except XPath?  And what can i do when passenger number is different?

Answer (score 0):

I have extracted the var declarations and the var increments, there seems to be a mismatch at the declaration statements that could be causing the problem, don't the var declarations need to start at the same number? Set them equal and re-try.

---

## var declaration

---

passen_serial_inf = 0

---

inf = 1

---

## var increments

---

inf = inf +1

---

```
    passen_serial_inf = passen_serial_inf + 1
```

---

```
passen_serial = passen_serial + 1
```

Comment: I declared var declaration and var increments for XPath because I need a dynamic XPath where I can use 1 XPath multiple times. like this  `CONTROLGROUPPASSENGER_PassengerInputViewPassengerView_DropDownListGender_"+ str(passen_serial_inf) + "_" + str(passen_serial_inf) + " `

Comment: Correct, but why are they set at declaration to different values? 1 and zero?  Shouldn't they  both be 0?

Comment: I edited the code in that code 'inf' is not needed for any XPath.

Comment: XPath element arrays start with 1 unlike most arrays, sorry - try starting each with 1 rather than 0.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025221/xpath-get-element-by-index

Comment: The problem is that the variables birth_year, birth_month, birth_day are not changing, thus you get the same answer from XPath with the same variables on retrieving the 2nd infant variable.